# Quiero hacer un script,que me salte el certificado de seguridad de https

Tags: javascript, html

tengo el siguiente problema mi aplicacion web tiene un iframe el cual accede a otra pagina sin certificado y me salta la seguridad y quiero hacer un script que automaticamente me salte dicha seguridad para que mi app pueda continuar.

Comment: Para evitar los puntos negativos debes de editar la pregunta y mostrar el codigo que tienes para ayudarte

Comment: Además de los consejos de Raul , revisa [ask] y realiza el [tour].

Comment: no poseo ningun codigo base,porque quiero generar un script desde cero con ayuda,pero ya alguien entendio y su respuesta fue de ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible realizar lo que pides, de otra forma carecería de sentido que sea HTTPS.

HTTPS usa un canal cifrado para transimitir la información, ese cifrado está basado en SSL, para que la conexión sea segura necesitas un certificado de ese tipo.

Sin embargo, para solucionar tu problema puedes instalar un certficado gratuito a tu sitio, ahora existen distintos pero yo te recomiendo este: [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)